# How i access redux store outside a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my Store.js file i have that code:

```
export const INSERIR_USUARIO = 'app/login/INSERIR_USUARIO';

export const INITIAL_STATE = {
  usuario: null,
};

export default function reducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action = {}) {
  if (action.type === INSERIR_USUARIO) {
    return {
      ...state,
      usuario: action.payload,
    };
  }
  return state;
}

export const attUser = (usuario) => ({
  type: INSERIR_USUARIO,
  payload: usuario,
});
```

Now, in my login.js file, i need to access the function "attUser". I imported the function but I don't know if it is being called. But in redux is not saving

```
import { attUser } from './Store';
export const saveToken = () => {
  attUser({ name: 'a', age: '13' });
};
```

How do I insert this item in redux outside of a react component?

Comment: Calling `attUser()` does literally nothing because all that function does is return an object. You need to `dispatch` it in order for it to affect the store. Why do you want to do this outside of a component? Please explain your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

```
export const attUser = (usuario) => ({
  type: INSERIR_USUARIO,
  payload: usuario,
});
```

`attUser` is an action creator. It creates a small object describing what to do, but otherwise doesn't cause any actual change. To have an effect, you then need to dispatch this action. You didn't show the line where you actually create the store, but assuming the store variable is named `store`, you'll do:

```
store.dispatch(attUser({ name: 'a', age: '13' }))
```

For more on dispatching actions, [see this page](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-2-concepts-data-flow#dispatch).

---

P.S: you specifically asked about how to do this outside of react, so that's what i gave as an example. If a react component needs to do this dispatching, you should use the techniques in react-redux ([useDispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch) for function components, [mapDispatchToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) for class components)

Comment: My store is in that first file. How can I put it in a variable?

Comment: Does that file have a line something like `const store = createStore(/* something something */)`? If so, you just need to export it, then import it where it's needed.

Comment: This store file doesn't have this createStore line. I tried to refactor into this but I couldn't

Comment: Ok, then if it's in some other file, import it from there. Or are you saying you don't call `createStore` anywhere in your codebase?